# TextBox line break visible but not counted in amount of lines

Tags: c#, textbox, editor, notepad++

I have a very large text file and if I open it in notepad++ it is shown normal without any line breaks. But if I use the standard editor in windows at some points I get a line break.

The strange thing is, that if I put the text file in a `TextBox` in my c# program it also makes the line break.
BUT if I count the lines of the `TextBox` the amount is the same as shown in Notepad++. The extra lines have some chars from the upper line. 
So I think it is maybe because there are to long?

Can someone explain to me why my `TextBox` and the editor sometimes make a line break and notepad++ doesn't? But the amount of counted lines are equal in all tools?

It must be a graphical issue I guess, but I don't know why.

Comment: Is word wrap active?

Comment: No it is disabled. But anyway there have be more lines then.

Comment: The text editor UltraEdit has the configuration setting *Maximum columns before line wraps* which has as default value 4096 and as maximum value 20000. This setting is mainly for video buffer restrictions. Years ago some video drivers had problems if the display line was too long. But this is just a soft wrap. The file content is not modified, i.e. no newline characters are inserted as it can be seen on line number gutter. Limiting the length of very long lines on displaying also helps viewing files with such long lines as horizontal scrolling with scroll bar is easier on shorter lines.

Comment: For example the longest line to display has 20000 characters and width of text window has 1000 pixels. Moving horizontal scroll bar just 1 pixel to left/right results in moving the text 20 characters left/right. Good luck on horizontal navigation with such a pixel : character ratio. Limiting maximum display length to 2000 characters changes the pixel to characters ratio to 1 : 2 which makes it much easier to scroll horizontally lets say 80 characters to left/right.